# Exception helper, does any one use it?

Tags: c#, exception

I have searched something that would help me to register, `exceptions` that i `throw`,
i have found this nice link: 
http://irwinj.blogspot.co.il/2010/07/generic-throwifnull-c-helper-method.html

But i would like to ask does any body else use helpers or might it be, that you are doing the old way of `explicit` `exception` throwing?

Like so: `throw new Exception("Message");`

***Maybe you have a more generic approach to do it***?

Comment: A lot of much magic, but to what end?

Comment: .NET generates the stack trace at the moment the exception is `throw`n, so doing things like the link you've referred to doesn't seem nice.

Comment: @pst i didn't understand you, what do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Maybe you have a more generic approach to do it?

Did you hear/read something about [Code Contracts](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/)?

Answer (score 0):

You may just use [Enterprise Library Exception Handling Application block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664698%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx). It provides a proven way to handle exceptions throughout the whole application.